# SEVERE: javax.faces.FacesException: Erreur d’argument : le paramètre «text» est null

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a problem, with JSF and Primesfaces.
I have a form with a list like the:

```
<h:form>
  <h:outputText value="Filtrer par client" for="filtreClient" />
  <p:selectOneMenu id="filtreClient" value="#{actionBean.action.codeClient}" effect="fade">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Sélectionnez" itemValue="" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{clientDao.listeClient}"  />
  </p:selectOneMenu>
</h:form>
```

It returns me this `error ==>SEVERE: javax.faces.FacesException: Erreur d’argument : le paramètre «text» est null.`(wich means that the parameter "text" is null).
What I don't understand is that i don't have a  parameter text in my application and what parameter? Parameter from a method? from a `httpRequest`?

Have you ever seen that kind of error?

Here is my stack trace :

```
SEVERE: javax.faces.FacesException: Erreur d’argument : le paramètre «text» est null.
  javax.faces.FacesException: Erreur d’argument : le paramètre «text» est null.
  at com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(ExceptionHandlerImpl.java:142)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1542)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:809)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:671)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:505)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:476)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:355)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:305)
at servlet.Login.doPost(Login.java:85)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:688)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1542)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Erreur d’argument : le paramètre «text» est null.
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlResponseWriter.writeText(HtmlResponseWriter.java:877)
at org.primefaces.component.selectonemenu.SelectOneMenuRenderer.encodeOption(SelectOneMenuRenderer.java:368)
at org.primefaces.component.selectonemenu.SelectOneMenuRenderer.encodeSelectItems(SelectOneMenuRenderer.java:333)
at org.primefaces.component.selectonemenu.SelectOneMenuRenderer.encodeInput(SelectOneMenuRenderer.java:114)
at org.primefaces.component.selectonemenu.SelectOneMenuRenderer.encodeMarkup(SelectOneMenuRenderer.java:91)
at org.primefaces.component.selectonemenu.SelectOneMenuRenderer.encodeEnd(SelectOneMenuRenderer.java:65)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1764)
at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1757)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
... 36 more
```

---

**Update**: Here is the `ClientDao` which creates the list:

```
public class ClientDao implements IClient, Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1951697664353493098L;

    public static String GET_ALL_CLIENT = "SELECT c.codeClient, c.nom , c.prenom FROM Client c ORDER BY c.name ASC ";


    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "dev")
    EntityManager em;

    private List<SelectItem> listeClient;
    private List<Client> resListeClient;
    private SelectItem selectItem;
    public List<SelectItem> getListeClient() {
        try {

            EntityManagerFactory emf = null;
            emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("dev");
            em = emf.createEntityManager();
            Query requete = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Client c ORDER BY c.nom ASC");
            resListeClient = requete.getResultList();
            listeClient = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
                for (Client c : resListeClient) {
                    if (c.getNom() != null) {
                        selectItem = new SelectItem();
                        selectItem.setValue(c.getCodeClient());
                        selectItem.setLabel(c.getNom() + " " + c.getPrenom());
                        listeClient.add(selectItem);
                    }
                }

        } catch (NoResultException e) {

            System.out.println("Aucun client trouvé" + e.getMessage()
                    + e.getCause());

        } finally {
            if (em != null) {
                em.close();
            }
        }

        return listeClient;
        // return null;

    }
```

Comment: English is the lingua franca in programming. It's strongly recommended  to reconfigure your development enviornment to use English instead of French. When you Google exact error messages in English, then you will get many many more helpful results/hints. The same applies to posting questions here on Stack Overflow. You will get much more chance in getting helpful answers if the code (class/method/field names, etc) and the error messages are entirely in English.

Comment: You are right, i will do this in the futur...Thank u.

Answer (score 0):

You concrete problem is you are generating a list of `SelectItem` object in getter method which is wrong. Migrate code for generating list in `@PostConstruct` method, and in getter just return that list:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
  try {
    EntityManagerFactory emf = null;
    emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("dev");
    em = emf.createEntityManager();
    Query requete = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Client c ORDER BY c.nom ASC");
    resListeClient = requete.getResultList();
    listeClient = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
        for (Client c : resListeClient) {
            if (c.getNom() != null) {
                selectItem = new SelectItem();
                selectItem.setValue(c.getCodeClient());
                selectItem.setLabel(c.getNom() + " " + c.getPrenom());
                listeClient.add(selectItem);
            }
        }

  } catch (NoResultException e) {

    System.out.println("Aucun client trouvé" + e.getMessage()
            + e.getCause());

  } finally {
    if (em != null) {
        em.close();
    }
  }
}

public List<SelectItem> getListeClient() {
  return listeClient;
}
```

Getter is called multiple times during JSF lifecycle so this is first bad because of performance. Also you should have same list during initial request and postback to have values properly set.

Comment: Thank u for answer, now it almost works i have the clients in my list but the compilation stop with this error Caused by: javax.el.ELException: /dashboard.xhtml: The class 'javax.faces.model.SelectItem' does not have the property 'nom'. The rest of page is not rendered.

Comment: SEVERE: javax.faces.FacesException: /dashboard.xhtml: The class 'javax.faces.model.SelectItem' does not have the property 'nom'.
javax.faces.FacesException: /dashboard.xhtml: The class 'javax.faces.model.SelectItem' does not have the property 'nom'.
 at com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(ExceptionHandlerImpl.java:142)
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119)
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
 at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)

Comment: at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1542)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:809)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:671)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:505)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:476)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:355)

Comment: Than your items ARE instance of `SelectItem` class but you probably didn't set properties good. Please post code for creating `listeClient`.

Comment: Merci beaucoup for u answer i have modified my code but now i am having this error=> Caused by: com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderException:
 com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException:
 Exception attempting to inject Remote ejb-ref name=controllers.ScheduleController/calendrierDao,
Remote 3.x interface =dao.CalendrierDao,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=dao.CalendrierDao,refType=Session (..)